# pandas groupby of DataFrame using Series of substrings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame which I would like to group by substrings of one of the columns. The substrings are given in another pandas Series (or a list). I have tried a number of things but I simply cannot get it to work.

I have this:

```
tst = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 11, 222, 3333, 44444],
                    'bla': ['ab', 'ba', 'ca', 'bc', 'db']})
test = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

I would like to group `tst` according to whether 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' (from `test`) is contained in `tst['bla']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.apply() is best here.

```
import pandas as pd
def funcx(x, test_str):
    return test_str in x['bla']


tst = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 11, 222, 3333, 44444],
                'bla': ['ab', 'ba', 'ca', 'bc', 'db']})
test = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
result = {}
for xstring in test:
    result[xstring] = tst.apply(funcx, args=( xstring), axis=1)

print result
```

gives us;

```
{'a': 0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool, 'c': 0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool, 'b': 0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool, 'd': 0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool}
```

this can then be used to select relevant rows;

```
>>print tst[result['a']]
  bla   id
  0  ab    0
  1  ba   11
  2  ca  222
```

Comment: More elegant than the apply function is to use  `result[xstring] = tst.bla.str.contains(xstring)`

Comment: Thanks for the the solution. First I was a bit worried that my real data (20M of csv files) would take a long time to be process with the for loop, but it was very quick. Initially, I had hoped for some one-line pandas magic, but this is a good and easy solution. Thanks!